# Um 'break' dentro de dois 'for' funciona na verdade como um continue?

Tags: c, loop, for

Se por acaso eu tiver um `break` dentro de dois `for`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        break;
    }
{
```

O `break` não fará o programa sair dos dois `for`, apenas do `for` de dentro, correto?
Então neste caso, este `break` funciona como um `continue` para o `for` que contém o `i`, porque ele vai pular o loop do `for` mais interno?

Tenho essa dúvida faz um tempo, gostaria de ter certeza se posso pensar desta maneira ou não.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, a diferença entre o `break` e o `continue`:

- O `continue` salta para a próxima iteração de ciclo. Ou seja, apenas ignora o resto do bloco de instruções de uma iteração.
- O `break` força a saída do ciclo. Ou seja, não salta apenas uma iteração, mas termina completamente a execução do ciclo.

Neste caso, na língua original (inglês) fica muito fácil perceber o que cada uma das instruções representa, basta acrescentar a palavra *loop*:

- *break loop* - quebra o loop/ciclo.
- *continue loop* - continua o loop/ciclo (salta uma iteração).

No teu caso em particular, como o `break` (unlabeled) apenas termina a execução do ciclo onde está inserido, terá o mesmo efeito prático que um `continue` no ciclo mais externo, ou seja, apenas irá saltar uma iteração.

> O `break` não fará o programa sair dos dois `for`, apenas do `for` de dentro, correto?

**Sim, correcto. Mas atenção:** Este comportamente resulta do facto de o segundo ciclo ser a única instrução no ciclo mais externo. Imagina que quem estiver a manter o teu código adiciona mais uma instrução no teu código. Algo assim:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        break;
    }
    //executa novo procedimento
    MyObject.funcaoMaravilha();
}
```

Neste caso o `break` não terá o mesmo efeito pois o fluxo de execução continua na instrução `MyObject.funcaoMaravilha();` e o `break` NÃO irá mais funcionar como um `continue` para o `for` que contém o `i`.

Para finalizar e ainda que a pergunta refira explicitamente à linguagem C, fica aqui uma pequena dica para quem usa Java. O Java permite o uso de "named/labeled"

```java
first:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    second:
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        break first;
    }
}
MyObject.fazCoisas();
```

Neste caso o `break` irá terminar a execução da instrução associada com a *tag* **first**. O fluxo de execução continua na instrução `MyObject.fazCoisas();` Para conseguir o mesmo efeito na linguagem C, necessitarias de algo como o `goto`.